# "LLDB Provided No Error String" - Problem with XCode

Tags: xcode

I'm experiencing an issue with running an opencv program in Xcode. I keep getting this error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6Gpu.png . Xcode works with other opencv programs, so I have no idea what would be causing this issue & how I would go about fixing it. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue. It was caused when I run the TensorFlow toolchain in Xcode.

Comment: Same, reported [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/swift/issues/532)

Comment: I am seeing a similar error. When I do, the final build product is coloured red. In my case, I think the build was failing quietly because my source was in blue sub folders, that arrived when I added files to the project, but selected folders. When I added all the files in a flat structure, the build succeeded and to problem went away. Maybe your problem is something else entirely, but who knows.

Answer (score 3):

Worked with me same step

I had a same problem. I have Just unchecked: Target-> Edit Scheme -> Run -> Info -> Debug executable.

Answer (score 1):

I had a same problem.
I have Just unchecked: Target-> Edit Scheme -> Run -> Info -> Debug executable.

It works for me.

Comment: where is Target located?

Comment: Be aware that breakpoints will not work if you uncheck this box.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>My solution was to delete /Application/Xcode.app as well as /Library/Developer and ~/Library/Developer and reinstall Xcode.</strike>

Edit: The error reappeared. Not sure why.

I had the Xcode-Beta versions installed and assume that that might have caused that.

Answer (score 0):

A solution has been provided [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/swift/issues/569), which would be:

```
sudo install_name_tool -add_rpath /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/ <toolchain path>/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Versions/A/LLDB
```

Answer (score 0):

My professor said it has to do with the way your files are set up in the IDE, if you have the program reading in files from a folder you imported, you need to remove the reference to the folder, and go back and import each file individually rather than the folder as a whole. The IDE just sees the folder and doesn't actually see the files inside essentially