# IDEDebugSessionErrorDomain: LLDB provided no error string

Tags: ios, c, xcode, macos, lldb

Building my Xcode 12.4 project is successful but a popup window immediately appears mentioning *"Could not launch project: LLDB provided no string error".*. (enhanced question related to ["LLDB Provided No Error String" - Problem with XCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62820548/lldb-provided-no-error-string-problem-with-xcode)).

Following this [thread](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/120282) and having tried all suggestions, including i) restarting xcode and computer, ii) sudo DevToolsSecurity -enable, iii) editing Product>Scheme (both in debug and release modes), I have obtained:

1. with "debug executable" checked:
   `Could not launch: LLDB provided no error string.

   ```
        Details

        Could not launch “testingC”
        Domain: IDEDebugSessionErrorDomain
        Code: 3
        Failure Reason: LLDB provided no error string.
        User Info: {
            DVTRadarComponentKey = 855031;
            RawLLDBErrorMessage = "LLDB provided no error string.";
        }
        --


        System Information

        macOS Version 10.15.7 (Build 19H2)
        Xcode 12.4 (17801) (Build 12D4e)
        Timestamp: 2021-02-14T16:05:44+01:00
   ```

2. with "debug executable" unchecked (same System Info):
   `Could not launch: LLDB provided no error string.

   ```
    Details

    Launch error
    Domain: IDELaunchErrorDomain
    Code: 9
    Recovery Suggestion: There is a problem launching using posix_spawn (error code: 2).
    --
   ```

From there, I found [this post](https://github.com/tensorflow/swift/issues/569) which seems to be relevant in this case, which I tried, resulting in:
" can't open file: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Versions/A/LLDB", which is normal as I have not LLDB installed.

In this case, what would be the LLDB command(s) to try here? Otherwise, how to fix these errors?

Comment: I am seeing a similar error. When I do, the final build product is coloured red. In my case, I think the build was failing quietly because my source was in blue sub folders, that arrived when I added files to the project, but selected folders. When I added all the files in a flat structure, the build succeeded and to problem went away. Maybe your problem is something else entirely, but who knows.

Comment: thanks, already tried this

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: can't remember sorrry